# Visualizing D2R rdf data using lodlive

Tags: javascript, rdf, data-visualization, linked-data, d2rq

I working on publishing linked data.

and I used D2R to publish data from relational database.

Now, I need to visualize these data, so I wanted to use lodlive script.

I got the project source code from https://github.com/withjam/ml-lodlive#dataset

I used this code to do that, but it didn't work!

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html style="width: 100%; height: 100%">
  <head>
    <title>LodLive Testing</title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="dist/ml-lodlive.all.css">
  </head>
  <body style="width: 100%; height: 100%">
    <div id="graph" style="width: 100%; height: 100%"></div>
    <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-2.1.3.min.js"></script>
    <script src="dist/ml-lodlive.complete.js"></script>
    <script src="js/profile/profile.example.js"></script>
    <script>
        MyProfileObject.connection['http:'].endpoint = 'http://localhost:1111/sparql'; // to use the out-of-the-box MarkLogic SPARQL support
        MyProfileObject.connection['http:'].accepts = 'application/sparql-results+json'; // for regular XHR requests be sure to add this header to receive json response
        MyProfileObject.endpoints.jsonp = false; // depending on if you are using jsonp
        MyProfileObject.endpoints.all = ''; // and additional query params you wish to include in every request

      'use strict';
      jQuery('#graph').lodlive({ profile: MyProfileObject, firstUri: 'http://localhost:1111/data/organization/2', ignoreBnodes: true }); // 'http://dbpedia.org/resource/Philadelphia_Flyers'
    </script>
  </body>
</html>
```

while the rdf data is

```
@prefix unio:    <http://tishreen.edu.sy/UniversityOntology.owl#> .
@prefix xhtml:   <http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml/vocab/#> .
@prefix d2rq:    <http://www.wiwiss.fu-berlin.de/suhl/bizer/D2RQ/0.1#> .
@prefix org:     <http://www.w3.org/ns/org#> .
@prefix geonames:  <http://www.geonames.org/ontology#> .
@prefix rdfs:    <http://www.w3.org/2000/01/rdf-schema#> .
@prefix prvTypes:  <http://purl.org/net/provenance/types#> .
@prefix event:   <http://purl.org/NET/c4dm/event.owl#> .
@prefix map:     <http://localhost:1111/resource/#> .
@prefix rdf:     <http://www.w3.org/1999/02/22-rdf-syntax-ns#> .
@prefix dc:      <http://purl.org/dc/terms/> .
@prefix prv:     <http://purl.org/net/provenance/ns#> .
@prefix db:      <http://localhost:1111/resource/> .
@prefix foaf:    <http://xmlns.com/foaf/0.1/> .
@prefix sp:      <http://spinrdf.org/sp#> .
@prefix void:    <http://rdfs.org/ns/void#> .
@prefix teach:   <http://linkedscience.org/teach/ns#> .
@prefix vcard:   <http://www.w3.org/2006/vcard/ns#> .
@prefix bibo:    <http://purl.org/ontology/bibo/> .
@prefix owl:     <http://www.w3.org/2002/07/owl#> .
@prefix xsd:     <http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema#> .
@prefix aiiso:   <http://purl.org/vocab/aiiso/schema#> .
@prefix vocab:   <http://localhost:1111/resource/vocab/> .
@prefix doap:    <http://usefulinc.com/ns/doap#> .

<http://localhost:1111/resource/organization/3>
      a       aiiso:College , <http://dbpedia.org/ontology/College> , foaf:Organization , owl:Thing , org:Organization ;
      rdfs:comment "about" ;
      rdfs:isDefinedBy <http://localhost:1111/data/organization/3> ;
      rdfs:label "كلية الهندسة المدنية" ;
      aiiso:part_of <http://localhost:1111/resource/organization/1> ;
      geonames:locatedIn <http://sws.geonames.org/7635195/> ;
      vcard:email "info@tishreen.edu.sy" ;
      vcard:telephone "041555888" ;
      org:identifier "5564" ;
      org:purpose "purpose" ;
      org:subOrganizationOf
              <http://localhost:1111/resource/organization/1> ;
      foaf:logo "http://url" ;
      foaf:page <http://localhost:1111/page/organization/3> ;
      foaf:phone "041222555" .

<http://localhost:1111/data/organization/3>
      a       foaf:Document , prv:DataItem ;
      rdfs:label "RDF Description of كلية الهندسة المدنية" ;
      dc:date "2017-10-26T20:08:47.974Z"^^xsd:dateTime ;
      prv:containedBy <http://localhost:1111/dataset> ;
      void:inDataset <http://localhost:1111/dataset> ;
      foaf:primaryTopic <http://localhost:1111/resource/organization/3> .
```

Comment: ML LodLive is optimized for pulling data from MarkLogic, right?  (In addition to other improvements.)  Have you actually loaded the D2R output into a MarkLogic database?  If not, you might want to just use the legacy LodLive: https://github.com/dvcama/LodLive and store your data in Virtuoso, or some other triplestore, possibly in combination with dvcama's SPARQL proxy.: https://github.com/dvcama/resource-to-sparqlresult .  I found setting up LodLive + Virtuoso on Ubuntu Linux pretty straightforward and could discuss that further if necessary.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I could do that using this HTML page:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html style="width: 100%; height: 100%">
  <head>
    <title>LodLive Testing</title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="dist/ml-lodlive.all.css">
  </head>

  <body style="width: 100%; height: 100%">
    <div id="graph" style="width: 100%; height: 100%"></div>
    <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-2.1.3.min.js"></script>
    <script src="dist/ml-lodlive.complete.js"></script>
    <script src="js/profile/profile.example.js"></script>
    <script>
      'use strict';
  jQuery('#graph').lodlive({ profile: ExampleProfile, firstUri:     'http://localhost:1111/data/organization/2', ignoreBnodes: true });
    </script>
  </body>
</html>
```

and created a profile file "profile.example.js" which declares that the endpoint is http://localhost:1111/sparql